# Trouble overriding toString on object/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, backbone.js

As the title says, I'm trying to implement some conditional display logic to my form built using [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms). The environment also uses Backbone.js, Underscore.js and jQuery.

I have reviewed the similar question here on SO "[backbone-forms with conditional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433314/backbone-forms-with-conditional-fields)", but our use case is a bit different: we have fields that depend on multiple conditions (e.g. only display if foo=1 and bar=2).

[*edit: I've already written a generic form change event handler to handle hiding and showing the different fields, so I don't want suggestions about that part.*]

I'm trying to use data attributes to contain a JSON representation of the field's conditions, but I'm open to other solutions. Here's roughly what I'm currently trying to achieve:

`<input id="field3" name="field3" data-conditional-conditions='{"field1":"yes","field2":"yes"}' type="text">`

I've discovered that backbone-forms uses jQuery's `attr()` method to set any properties specified in the model's `schema` ([here's the relevant line in backbone-forms' source](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/master/src/editor.js#L47)), and it seems that `attr()` in turn uses `Object.prototype.toString()` to represent an object as a value when rendering the editor.*

So what I've been trying to do is implement a `Conditions` object as follows:

```
var Conditions = function(args){

    c = {
        toString: function(){
            return(JSON.stringify( _.omit(this, _.functions(this)) ));
        }
    };

    c.toString = _.bind(c.toString, c); //makes 'this' refer to the 'c' object

    args = _.isObject(args) ? args : {}; //default value for args

    c = _.defaults(c, args); //sets object key/value pairs from arguments

    return c;
};
```

My goal with the above was to replace the `toString()` method with one that would return a JSON-formatted representation of the object, without having to modify backbone-forms.

Unfortunately, the above doesn't quite work, as the form field appears as follows:

`<input id="field3" name="field3" tostring="{"data-conditional-conditions":{"field1":"yes","field2":"yes"}}" data-conditional-conditions="[object Object]" type="text">`

I'm reaching the end of my JavaScript knowledge, and frustrated by what's going on. I've tried using IIFEs and returning c.toString from my Conditions function, but neither of those have worked.

Thanks for reading, and I look forward to your suggestions!

**: I've inferred this because if I call `attr({"data-key": {"foo": "bar"} })`, the result looks like `<div data-key="[object Object]">`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I was pretty close, but just needed to do things a bit differently.

What I ended up doing to solve it was

- iterate over every `key, value` of the `args` object parameter (which I get from `arguments[0]` in this case)
- detect if `value` is an object
- if so, assign the value of `args[key]` to an IIFE that returns a JSON representation of the object `value`.

The IIFE turns out to be necessary because it maintains the value of `value` even when we change scope.

Here's my completed and working Conditions class:

```
var Conditions = function(){

    var args = arguments[0];

    //if we didn't call Conditions() with 'new', this next bit handles that
    if (!(this instanceof Conditions)){
        return new Conditions(args);
    }

    //default value for 'args' if we don't have an arguments object
    if (!_.isObject(args)){
        args = {};
    }

    _.each(args, function(val, key, obj){
        //detect where value is object
        if (_.isObject(val)){
            //replace these values with objectToJSON(value)
            args[key] = (function(obj){ return(JSON.stringify(obj)) })(val);
        }
    });

    return args;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion, but I'd first ask yourself whether those conditions belong in an attribute in the first place. That's one reason I loathe the AngularJS philosophy -- there's too much damn logic in the view. All philosophies aside...

In the other SO thread, there's the following in the code example:

```
 form.on('inputType:change', function(form, editor) {         
    form.fields['line'].$el.toggle();
    form.fields['area'].$el.toggle();
});
```

One thing you could do, although there might be a cleaner refactoring to apply (I don't know backbone-forms very well), is the following:

```
// Hide field 3.
form.fields['field3'].$el.hide();

function shouldShowField3(form) {
  return (form.fields['field1'].getValue() == 'yes' && form.fields['field2'].getValue() == 'yes')
}

function toggleField3(form, events) {
  if shouldShowField3(form) {
    form.fields['field3'].show()
  } else {
    form.fields['field3'].hide()
  }
}

form.on('field1:change', toggleField3);
form.on('field2:change', toggleField3);
```

So basically, we're potentially toggling the visibility of the field every time we change the value of the two dependents.